# Magento 2.1.8 multiple JavaScript Requests

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, minified-js, minify

I have set following configurations in admin ;
 `Enable JavaScript Bundling: Yes`
 `Merge JavaScript Files: Yes`
 `Minify JavaScript Files: Yes`
 and have done similar with CSS.
 When I test my site with http://www.webpagetest.org I still see multiple JavaScript Requests - see screenshot. The domain is http://www.extenderstore.com.au - why is this occurring?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2563

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Magento documentation, some JavaScript files are **excluded** from JavaScript Bundle file.

Moreover you must be in **production mode**.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/js-bundling.html

You can fine tuning the exclude list in your custom theme :

```
<vars module="Js_Bundle">
    <var name="bundle_size">1MB</var>
</vars>
<exclude>
    <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.min.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.details.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.details.min.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.hoverIntent.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::requirejs/require.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::requirejs/text.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::date-format-normalizer.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::legacy-build.min.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::mage/captcha.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::mage/dropdown_old.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::mage/list.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::mage/loader_old.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::mage/webapi.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::mage/zoom.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::mage/translate-inline-vde.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::mage/requirejs/mixins.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::mage/requirejs/static.js</item>
    <item type="file">Magento_Customer::js/zxcvbn.js</item>
    <item type="file">Magento_Catalog::js/zoom.js</item>
    <item type="file">Magento_Ui::js/lib/step-wizard.js</item>
    <item type="file">Magento_Ui::js/form/element/ui-select.js</item>
    <item type="file">Magento_Ui::js/form/element/file-uploader.js</item>
    <item type="file">Magento_Ui::js/form/components/insert.js</item>
    <item type="file">Magento_Ui::js/form/components/insert-listing.js</item>
    <item type="directory">Magento_Ui::js/timeline</item>
    <item type="directory">Magento_Ui::js/grid</item>
    <item type="directory">Magento_Ui::js/dynamic-rows</item>
    <item type="directory">Magento_Ui::templates/timeline</item>
    <item type="directory">Magento_Ui::templates/grid</item>
    <item type="directory">Magento_Ui::templates/dynamic-rows</item>
    <item type="directory">Magento_Swagger::swagger-ui</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::modernizr</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::tiny_mce</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::varien</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::jquery/editableMultiselect</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::jquery/jstree</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::jquery/fileUploader</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::css</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::lib</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::extjs</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::prototype</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::scriptaculous</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::less</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::mage/adminhtml</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::mage/backend</item>
</exclude>
```